# IntelliJ - Suppress code auto-formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting, intellij-14

IntelliJ 14 always wants to format my code on save. Normally this is fine, but if I'm working on a file that's very poorly formatted, I'd rather it not do this. Otherwise, my changes get lost among the formatting changes. Is there a way to turn this off, either selectively or even permanently? The only thing I could find were the "@formatter" tags, which *are* enabled, but even when I put the whole file inside those tags, IntelliJ *still* wants to format it.

Comment: I've never encountered this behavior in IntelliJ. By the way this happens only when you explicitly hit CTRL+S? Because IntelliJ uses autosave so if it reformatted the code on each autosave it would be rather annoying behavior :)

Comment: That's correct, the formatting happens when I explicitly save dirty editors.

Comment: I'm not aware of any option (except remapping CTRL+S to reformat code action) which would enable this behavior. Are you using any plugins that might contain this functionality?

Comment: Good question. Maybe I am. I'll check into that.

Comment: Thanks, @BohuslavBurghardt, that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There we go. What I was seeing was not full formatting, but only IntelliJ stripping trailing spaces. Once I found that setting and changed it from "All" to "Modified Lines", the saves were no longer intrusive.

Comment: @ps. it's just a setting on the editor. Any file you edit and save will be affected.